# AngularJS: Controller should hold big array of items or controller for each item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular v1.3.15.
My controller displays a big table from an array of objects:

```
$scope.table = [
  { name: "A",
    availableConnection: [
      { id: 1, displayName: "Foo" },
      { id: 2, displayName: "Bar" },
      ...
    ]},
  { name: "B",
        availableConnection: [
          { id: 1, displayName: "Doo" },
          { id: 2, displayName: "Boo" },
          ...
        ]},
  ...
];
```

I was wondering if it is better that my controller will hold controller for each cell in the array $scope.table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in table" ng-controller="RowController">
      <td>
          <select ng-options="a.displayName for a in availableConnection" >                          
          </select>
      </td>
</tr>
```

I cant copy my code because it's inside private network.
This example explains what i meant.
* Also the whole page got an controller so it means the hole table is inside controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to use nested controllers or not is judgement call, but [this tutorial  states](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&t=30m34s) that **scope should refer to the model, not be the model** -- so don't model/put your data into scopes. Your models/data should normally be in a service.

When developing an Angular application, at first try to think about your **models**. Put them in services or factory with APIs to get/edit/manipulate the models. Then next step is to design your views. Each view should project/use/manipulate some subset of your models. **Create a controller for each view that simply glues the needed subset of the models to the view.** Make your controllers as thin as possible.

So, in my view, it is better **not** to use nested controllers as you should know how [to properly use nested controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567679/angularjs-controller-not-working-in-nested-controller). Your code gets more complicated, if you use nested controllers.

Answer (score 2):

Controllers in AngularJS are usually not used for any "heavy lifting", including big data sets. 
If you have a large data set, you should store your values in a JSON file. You can use the $http service to retrieve the data:

```
 $http.get("my_data.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.table = response.data;
    });
```

You can then use only one controller for many JSON files, and then print it on your HTML file. Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not storing the data in the controller. i get it from api. the question was if i need to make controller for every row in the table or just one for the whole page

Comment: You should use one controller for the whole table. If you use a controller for every row, then you have no need for ng-repeat, which in the end will stop you from repeating yourself in your code. I hope my answer is clear! :)